# Files not created when using Eclipse Master/Detail Flow Template

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

Trying to create a Fragments- project in Eclipse through "New Android Application Project". When I click Master/Detail Flow, the necessary files (Java/Activity, XML/Layout, Android Manifest) are not being created. I've Googled and searched here, but can't find a solution. I've tried restarting eclipse and updating Eclipse and the SDK- tools. If I do the exact same thing, but choose "Blank Activity", the files are created as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem "solved itself". I found no solution to the problem, but after a few days, when I tried the exact same ting again, the files were created.